# Are enemy subtypes level restricted?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've noticed in Skyrim that enemies such as bandits, namely the weakest type that is, just bandits become less and less common the more you level up.

I was wondering do some enemies stop appearing all together after you reach a certain level?

I don't want to not encounter Blood Dragons anymore just because I'm to high for them :(

They look so cool!

Comment: This may be of interest: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim%3aLeveling#Effects_of_Leveling

Answer (score 2):

This is correct. Lower leveled bandits and whatnot become more scarce. Of course, the wikis can give you detailed information on leveled lists, which include enemies, loot, and non-unique NPCs.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some lower leveled enemies do become completely extinct as you level up.

You can fix this with a variety of mods, such as this one
http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/9857/?